# ReactJS setState variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter an array and set its state with the filtered version of that array. My code looks like this:

```
    class Overview extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
          card: []
        }
      }

      deleteItem(id) {
        fetch('/api/v1/story/'+id,{
          method: 'DELETE',
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          if(response['response'] == "success"){
            this.setState({
              //this is where it says this.state is undefined
              card: this.state.card.filter(s => s.storyId !== id)
            });
          }else{
            toastr.warning('dit item is al verwijderd', '', {positionClass: "toast-bottom-right", timeOut: 40000})
          }
        })
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/v1/overview')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({ 
              card: responseJson
            })
          })
      }
      render(){return (    
       <div className="deleteItem" onClick={deleteItem}>
       </div>
      )}
```

What happens here is that the page loads and fills the cards array (which works), the cards then get loaded in the DOM and when u click on an icon it should filter out the removed card from the card array and then set the state to the filtered array.

But whenever i get to this.setstate and try to filter it gives me this error:

> app.js:66418 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'card' of undefined

I hope i explained it good enough and that someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot get that error with this code, since the actual problem you'd observe would be invoking undefined `deleteItem`

Comment: `bind` your function in the constructor: `this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this)` Also, how do you get `id` in your function?

Comment: as above ^^^, and it should also be `onClick={this.deleteItem}`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
Also, why you make 2 .then()? Why not just one and use `()=>{and here you can write more than one line}`

Edited: If you use arrow functions you don't need to bind the context of THIS
https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480

If you don't want to use arrow functions, you need to bind the context in the constructor 
`this.myFunction= this.myFunction.bind(this);`

```js
class Overview extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
          card: []
        }
      }

      deleteItem=(id)=> {
        fetch('/api/v1/story/'+id,{
          method: 'DELETE',
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          if(response['response'] == "success"){
            this.setState({
              //this is where it says this.state is undefined
              card: this.state.card.filter(s => s.storyId !== id)
            });
          }else{
            toastr.warning('dit item is al verwijderd', '', {positionClass: "toast-bottom-right", timeOut: 40000})
          }
        })
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/v1/overview')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({ 
              card: responseJson
            })
          })
      }
      render(){return (    
       <div className="deleteItem" onClick={this.deleteItem}>
       </div>
      )}
```

Comment: It would be better to explain which part of your suggestion solves OP's problem. For example, you are using an arrow function, so OP can use `this` context. Try to avoid just dropping the answer :) Also, two `then` is needed here since `fetch` returns a promise in the first response (body).